# Apache SparkML Dead Slow with K-Means with 5.5 million jdbc records

Tags: java, sql-server-2008, jdbc, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

Using **apache spark 1.6** in **local mode** within **tomcat server** Web based application and the machine has **64GB of RAM** and **16 cores**.

Tomcat is assigned 20GB of memory. When initializing spark context, **spark driver and executor both has been assigned 15GB of memory.**

While database (**MS SQL Server 2008 R2**) table contains 5.5 million records and 200 columns.

**Problem :**

- When k-means algorithm is executed it stucks at jdbc operation
  (probably reading data from database table - aprox. 25 minutes for retrieval).
- K means itself does the Job in aprox 7 minutes.
- Then it stuck again (may be writing results back to database in a new table - never returns Two hours until killed the job manually).

**Question** # Need Advice to improve performance to acceptable time, we expected whole job to finish under or may be around 10 minutes ? any guidance would be appreciated.

**Code snippet for executing spark mlib k-means**

```
DataFrame dataFrame = sparkContextSQL.read().format("jdbc").options(options).load();
JavaRDD<Row> javaRDD = dataFrame.toJavaRDD();
JavaRDD<Vector> javaRddVector = javaRDD.map(new NumericFieldsToVector());
javaRddVector.cache();

// model configurations
int numberOfClusters = 5;
int numberOfIterations = 20;

KMeansModel kmeansModel = KMeans.train(javaRddVector.rdd(), numberOfClusters, numberOfIterations);
JavaRDD<Row> rowsWithClusterPrediction = javaRDD.map(new FieldsWithClusterNumber(kmeansModel));

javaRddVector.unpersist();

// ========== create new-schema
List<StructField> newFields = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(dataFrame.schema().fields()));
newFields.add(DataTypes.createStructField("cluster_number", DataTypes.StringType, true));
StructType newSchema = DataTypes.createStructType(newFields);
DataFrame newDataFrame = sparkContextSQL.createDataFrame(rowsWithClusterPrediction, newSchema);

// Save newDataFrame into Database Table
String tableName = "kmeans" + UUID.randomUUID().toString().replaceAll("-", "");
newDataFrame.write().jdbc(fullUrl, tableName, new Properties());
```

Comment: Title looks misleading, don't you think? Is there anything K-means specific here? How does it perform when you execute reads / writes alone?

Comment: @zero323 I am sorry, if the title seems misleading. Can you please advice me a better title because i am stuck in this situation. I did noticed that the actual jdbc reads and writes are culprit, no matter you pass it through k-means algorithm or not. can you advice any diagnosis.?

Comment: @zero323 originally once our piece of code is tested our real data is over 400 billion records. but right now it is stalling against only 5 million records.

Comment: Nothing to apologize although there I doubt there is much we can do here to help you. Nevertheless I would try to isolate the problem first. If K-means is not an important factor just drop it. Is Spark fundamental? Do you get similar results when you perform data reads / writes from the same machine using other tools? Do you have a sufficient bandwidth? How database performs when you execute large local reads / writes? Do you see anything out of order when you use your standard DB monitoring tools?

Comment: @zero323 i am testing it more closely as i am writing this reply, the data set in the table is 5.5 million with 200 columns, when i executed the same query directly in MS SQL Server Management Studio which i am using in spark jdbc connection, it took 14.59 minutes to load the results and the SQL Server footprint increased to 4GB of memory. Bandwidth is not a problem for now as it is in local machine, the table i am reading is indexed and has a proper primary key as well. The query i am running is "SELECT [column names..] FROM mytable", i expected spark to atleast read as good as direct query.

Comment: @zero323 i do noticed that the number of columns in the select query are directly proportional to total time it takes to retrieve the data. I wonder if Spark has a bulk copy/read to load data into its cache for analysis.?

Comment: Try running it with very small data first, say 1000 records only. This will rule out that your code is working or not. If yes, them increase the data-size in steps, and try to find out which of the step (read or train or write) is taking up most of the time Or, not scaling up well.